# How to make: "You have 30 form submissions for today"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a website that users submit the HTML form more than 50 times a day (Most of the users do that).

What I want to do is: To make the user have 30 submissions a day ONLY. If they submit more than 30 times, it will say "You have reached the limit number of submissions, please try again after 5h 30m 10s".

Example: www.prankdial.com (The top right, it says you have 2 free calls. When you use the 2 free calls, it will show you the time when you can call again) That's exactly what I want; but instead of **2 free calls**, I want to make it **30 form submissions**.
Is it possible to do that?

My form: jsfiddle.net/FEF7D/4/

Thanks & if you need any other info about my question, please comment below :)

Comment: So what are your thoughts? "Is it possible to do that?" --- yes it is. Is your only question answered?

Comment: its very simple. You just do a count on the submitted amount of forms per user. If it goes above 30, you add that statement. How to do that? That completely depends on your system. I cant help you with that.

Comment: @zerkms, But I thought Prankdial.com has very good programmers that's how they made it, me; I am new to the programming :)

Comment: We dont "make" things. We correct your trials. StackOverflow is not about your demands is our programming pleasure.

Comment: @Dorvalla I dont think he has users per se, he probably has to limit per ip, edit: actually he does say per user.

Comment: @andrew Well thats his challenge. To figure out a way what would work for him best. And i gave him just a directional thought, where i was asuming he saves the information from his users :)

Comment: Yes, I think prankdial.com uses limit per ip, because I downloaded ultrasurf proxy once and changed the ip, it gave me another 2 free calls because the website thinks I am a different person from a different ip

Comment: So here is what we gave you already. You log the IP adres from the user, who submits the form. Since you submitting forms, i am asuming you store them in a database. So now you simply make a query that has to be run when a user submits a form. Allow it do a count within the database. IF a certain IP has 30 entrees in the database on a specific date, dont allow them acces (an if, else statement within your goto.php)

Comment: It is possible for pro programmers, not for me. I am VERY new to programming. You said to "simply make a query that has to be run when a user submits a form", honestly;I don't know how to make that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write you a complete solution but you can get a user ip in php with:

```
 //$userip = ($_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

**Edit:**

```
      $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

and update the db record with something like

```
$query = "update submits set usercount = (select usercount from submits where user = $user)+1 where userip = '$userip'";
```

Comment: Your `$userip` is a total bs, sorry. You **CANNOT** rely on `X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Comment: @zerkms in what way? it works fine for me edit: ok, is there a better solution to obtain ip?

Comment: in what way *what*? User can specify anything into `X_FORWARDED_FOR`. The only reliable way to obtain IP is to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (we're talking about a non reverse-proxied web server). PS: of course it works, but user can fool you.

Comment: `X_FORWARDED_FOR` **IS NOT RELIABLE**. A user can put **ANYTHING** there. Do you realize that? So if one wanted to forge their IP - you're providing them an easy way of doing so.

Comment: nope, i did not realize that. thanks for the heads up